# Guarantee Continuous conduction mode dc/dc buck converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

In a buck converter the continuous conduction mode it depends on following equation:

$$ L_{min} \geq \frac{(1-D)R}{2f_s} $$

For a fixed load and inductance value, the operation mode will depend on the switching frequency.

For  following specifications:

$$ V_i = 30V $$
$$ R = 6\Omega $$
$$ L = 43 \mu H$$

I made the following plot:

[image]

Where yellow line is the output current, and the curves represents the minimum current required to operate in CCM at a given frequency. According to that, any Fs over 100 kHz will guarantee CCM in all range for that specific load and for any bigger one.

To find the minimum switching frequency to operate in CCM search iteratively the frequency where the line and the curve is tangent ang got: Fs = 70859Hz.

[image]

Is this a proper way to approach this problem or there is a better/easier alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few observations: -

- Most buck converters are voltage regulators so, if the load is fixed (3.5 ohms) the graphs plotting load current against duty cycle take you down a non-constant output voltage situation - this seems to restrict your ideas to very few applications (CC applications).
- Having the load resistor fixed in value also restricts the application even more so I'm even less inclined to see the benefits of this approach.
- A lot of modern buck regulators are now becoming synchronous and the excessive ripple seen in these types of converter (what would be previously due to DCM) is a thing of the past IMHO.

Maybe I've missed some intrinsic benefit about your process/approach?

Comment: I see, my next project would definitely be a synchronous converter. In this specific case the converter will only work with loads of 6 ohm or below, until 2 ohm. The purpose of the converter is to heat the load and then it will turn off. The heating process needs to be progressive so the converter output will basically follow the yellow line. Since the load range is bounded I thought on design it to work always in CCM, that way the ramp will be more smooth since the system will always have the same transfer function.

Comment: The thermal mass of what you are heating would probably make DCM perfectly OK.